# Get DNS server IP addresses from the adapter?

Tags: c, windows, dns

I am unable to get the DNS Server IP address using C. I have tried using `IP_ADAPTER_INFO` however it only gets the Primary and Secondary WINS Server IP address using `pAdapter->PrimaryWinsServer` and `pAdapter->SecondaryWinsServer`.

And based on my knowledge the WINS server and the DNS server are two different types of servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GetAdaptersAddresses()`,  and see the `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESS` structure.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help! But I was wondering how are you able to print/view the `FirstDnsServerAddress` since the datatype is `PIP_ADAPTER_MULTICAST_ADDRESS`?